# How do I automatically export NFS shares on reboot?

Tags: linux, nfs

I inherited a small network where each machine is an NFS server/client, and exports a /data folder to all the other machines. I've added a machine that I'd like to have the same functionality, and updated the networks /etc/fstab and /etc/exports accordingly.

However upon reboot, the new machine does not automatically create the export table, so I have to manually `sudo exportfs -a` for that machine, then `sudo mount -a` on the clients to get them connected. I've already added the shares to /etc/exports, as some articles have suggested. What is the default behavior for NFS? It doesn't appear that the old machines have a /etc/profile line for exporting the shares that I can find.

Comment: go to /etc/rcX.d (where X is your run-level (who -r)), do you have any nfs startup script ? (grep exportfs * )

Comment: There's a link to init.d/nfs-kernel-server which contains a call to exportfs on 'start'

Comment: running `sudo service nfs-kernel-server start` will export the directories, but it still doesn't stick on reboot...

Comment: If you figured this out, I'd love to hear the solution!

Answer (score 1):

If your systems use the utility `systemctl` then make sure you `enable` the `nfs` services - at least `nfs-server.service` and `nfs-utils.service`; only services that are in the `enabled` state are started on reboot.